# XPath: select node that contains ONLY a certain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath

I'm making a parser in rails for a website and I'm having trouble selecting only the stuff I want.

I want to select the following sibling to a td-tag that contains ONLY "**World:**", but there's another td-tag containing "**Former World:**" that I get too, and I don't want to select that one.

Here's my XPath selection:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'World:')]/following-sibling::td
```

So I want the tag containing ONLY "**World:**" and not the other one containing "**Former World:**"

Any ideas? Spent hours searching for a solution, but now I ended up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you change it to

```
//td[text()='World:']/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I figured it wasn't harder than that... But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing the text with equals?

```
//td[text() = 'World:']/following-sibling::td

or

//td[. = 'World:']/following-sibling::td
```